# Bike shaking while in half clutch

Tags: clutch, vibration

This is a UM Renegade Commando.

The whole bike starts shaking when I leave the clutch, and I can't drive my vehicle in half-clutch.

This problem usually occurs after the clutch is continuously used for sometime. It's so hard to drive the bike in traffic as I can't let go of the clutch completely and it shakes a lot in half-clutch.

Please help regarding if I need to change my clutch plate or something else. Even the gear shifting is bit hard nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

This could be the clutch as you say or it could be a symptom of loose / broken engine mounts. Both need to be checked.

As a note, if by « half-clutch » you mean slipping the clutch then this is not good practise for long periods : clutch should be released fully as soon as possible to minimise wear...

Comment: a wet clutch is designed to be slipped on a bike, it promotes smoother acceleration.

Comment: @Mauro so the question is then “is this bike fitted with a wet clutch”?

Comment: According to https://auto.ndtv.com/um-motorcycles-bikes/renegade-commando it is a wet multiplate clutch...

Comment: Also what is “long periods” - smooth acceleration does that need clutch slipping through the complete rev range or just enough to engage properly...